# deploy node.js app to an actual www.mywebsite.com website

Tags: node.js, web

Here's a noob question. I made a small app in node.js and to see it I have to go to localhost:4000 in my web browser. How can I publish it in an actual website that everybody can see? I already have a domain name and a hosting service.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your hosting service?

Answer (score 1):

Your hosting service may not actually support Node. If it doesn't let you install and run your own software then you may be out of luck.

Generally you have few options:

1. You can host it yourself on your own machine but it will not be as easy and efficient as using a service for hosting, unless you have a high quality symmetric internet connection with low latency and high bandwidth.
2. You can host it cheaply on a VPS using Digital Ocean, Vultr or AWS in which case you will have to configure Node yourself and install all of the databases and other software that you need.
3. Or you can use managed platforms like Heroku for Node (and Compose for databse like Mongo that you will probably also need) in which case the price will be higher but everything will be taken care of for you.

It depends on what costs are you willing to take, both in terms of service fees and your time and expertise needed to configure and maintain different layers of the system.

Answer (score -1):

IMO the simplest way to deploy a Node app is with Heroku. You can find the documentation [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction).

It's free, and basically just requires that you create an app and then push your code to Heroku. It takes care of the rest for you!